# NSNumber formatting currency style giving wrong output

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using NSNumberFormatter with NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle , it is working fine as long as if I give small number as a input but if I give large number specifically more than 7 digits then it is rounding up 7th digit and adding 0 after that:
For example,If my number is : 12345678 
then output is : 12,345,680

If my number is : 123456789 
then output is : 123,456,800

My code is like below :

```
NSNumberFormatter* numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setFormatterBehavior: NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
NSLog(@"%@",[numberFormatter stringFromNumber: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:value]]);
```

So please help me with the workaround

Comment: i wonder something like `[formatter setUsesSignificantDigits:YES];
[formatter setMaximumSignificantDigits:10];` would work?

Comment: Using the same code in playground with swift the result seems correct, in which locale are you testing it?

Comment: @Andrea: Getting this issue in all locale

Answer (score 0):

You should use `NSDecimalNumber` for financial purposes.

```
NSLog(@"%@",[numberFormatter stringFromNumber: [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"123456789"]]);
```